# algebraic conjugate and sum of roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

[image]

In above lemma, why $|a'| \leq 1$ still holds? I didn't see how it relates to "algebraic conjugate of a root of unity is also a root of unity", since $a$ is the sum of unity.

(definition of algebraic conjugate: http://planetmath.org/algebraicconjugates)

Comment: Each $|\epsilon_i|$. Their average is inside their convex hull, their convex hull is inside the unit disc.

Comment: @Pp.. How is that related to $a'$?

Comment: When you conjugate $a$ you get an average of some $\epsilon_i$. You know, the $\epsilon_i$ just get moved around. $\sigma(\frac{\sum \epsilon_i}{n})=\frac{\sum\sigma(\epsilon_i)}{n}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $\sigma (\sum \epsilon_i/n) = \sum\sigma(\epsilon_i)/n$, since each $|\sigma(\epsilon_i)|=1$, $|a'|=|\sigma(a)|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the triangle inequality.

(Each conjugate of each $\varepsilon_i$ is a root of unity, and so has absolute value $1$.)